# Record speech time in video conferences?

Tags: logs, audio, video

We all use a lot of Zoom, Skype, Meet these days.

I tend to talk more than I want to when in online meetings, so I was wondering if anyone has ideas on how to quantify how much I actually talk during a meeting :blush:

I was thinking about a script that records the number of seconds the microphone is active, but I'm open to other solutions.

Comment: ask for feedback from the other members in the meeting ... explain that it is for professional development

Comment: actually I want to measure it *during* the meeting, so I could set myself a target (number of minutes I can talk)